# MySQL Output different values by the same id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database containing two tables:

1. `products_attributes ( id , image )`
2. `options_values ( id , text )`

The id value is the same in both tables. Now I need to output the text and the image based on the same id from both tables.

Then possibly base this on the loop. I have created something like this, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM products_attributes JOIN options_values WHERE BY
 id=id ASC LIMIT 0,40";
$sqlresult = @mysql_query($sqlquery);
while ($content = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    echo "<img src='$content[1]'/> $content[2]";
}
```

@EDIT

So the query ended up like this, however I can not get the attributes_image (table column name) to display. It does however work using the numerical system.

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM zen_products_attributes pa JOIN zen_products_options_values ov ON pa.options_values_id = ov.products_options_values_id LIMIT 0,40;";
$sqlresult = @mysql_query ($sqlquery);
while ($content = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult, MYSQL_NUM)){

    echo $content['attributes_image'];

;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1:You need to use alias for tables when you are joining on same column
> name to avoid ambiguity.i.e 'id=id' is wrong.
>
> 2.Syntax error.there is no 'WHERE BY' in mysql.

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM 
 products_attributes pa 
JOIN options_values ov 
on pa.id=ov.id ASC LIMIT 0,40";
```

Edit answer:

```
while ($content = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult, MYSQL_NUM)){

    echo $content['attributes_image'];

;}
```

--^(extra semi colon,**remove this**)

Comment: How do I go about outputting the data from those tables. As I'd like it to only display data that has the exact the same id.
ie. Table 1 - id:1 Green, id:2 Red, id:3 Yellow
Table 2 - id:1 green.jpg, id:2 red.jpg, id:3 yellow.jpg

The PHP quarry will display the text and the image based on the same ID.

Comment: @DamianJanik please elaborate or if possible update your question.

Comment: @DamianJanik the query i have written will do the same as we are joining on id value.

Comment: What I mean is how would I go about using PHP in this case.  As previously I was able to retrieve the data using $content[1], now I have two tables and not sure how to go about getting it from both tables. As my tables contain more columns and I need to specify the data I'd like to retrieve.

Comment: just give the index as name like this $content['id'],$content['image']

Comment: specifying name as index will remove your confusions.

Comment: @DamianJanik i updated my answer.have a look.and still if you have doubts please let me know.

Comment: Have a look into my updated post. At the moment am struggling with the accurate output from both tables.

Comment: @damek132 i updated my answer as per your edit.you have a typo.see my answer

Comment: still nothing, I tried few versions like: $content['attributes_image'] - $content[attributes_image] - $content['attributes_image']; but nothing appears to be working...

Comment: Also do columns within the tables need to be specified in the MySQL quary? Such as 'attributes_image' that belongs to the zen_products_attributes table? If so, where would I add it?

Comment: @damek132 run the query in phpmyadmin and tell me which all column you get?

Comment: Sweet I did the quary in PHPAdmin and I managed just to use the numbers as the tables were correctly joined. Now, one last thing, I have got a column called: options_id, numerical data there goes from 1 to 3, any chance that I could only display just the data that has options_id set to 1?

Comment: ya you can.just add a condition in your query as " and options_id=1"    SELECT * FROM 
 products_attributes pa 
JOIN options_values ov 
on pa.id=ov.id where pa.options_id=1 ASC LIMIT 0,40

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
   $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM products_attributes JOIN options_values 
               ON products_attributes.id=options_values.id ASC LIMIT 0,40";
```

Comment: just curious what does 'WHERE BY ' does?

Comment: @Mrcoder oops my bad!!!i have copied the query from OP's post,didnt recognized it,thanks for correcting

Comment: How do I go about displaying the results in a PHP $content form, using your example?

Answer (score 0):

if you have fields with same name give them alias.

```
SELECT p.`desc` as description, v.`desc` FROM products_attributes as p
JOIN options_values as v ON  p.id=v.id
ASC LIMIT 0,40
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    products_attributes pa
JOIN
    options_values ov
ON
    pa.id = ov.id
LIMIT
    0,40;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM products_attributes AS pa JOIN options_values AS ov ON pa.id=ov.id ORDER BY ov.id ASC LIMIT 0,40
```